# Codeception: $i->see(text) but not $i->click(text)

Tags: php, codeception

I've searching for all posts on stackoverflow but with no success.

This works:

```
$I->amOnUrl('https://www.youtube.com');
$I->amOnPage('/watch?v=l03aH7TWLck');
$I->click('button[is="paper-icon-button-light"][id="button"]');
$I->wait(2);
$I->makeScreenshot('snap');
$I->see('Report'); <--Success
$I->click('Report'); <--Success
```

But this doesn't

```
$I->amOnUrl('https://www.youtube.com');
$I->amOnPage('/watch?v=l03aH7TWLck');
$I->click('button[is="paper-icon-button-light"][id="button"]');
$I->wait(2);
$I->makeScreenshot('snap');
$I->see('Open transcript'); <--Success
$I->click('Open transcript'); <--Error
```

This is the error which the console throws:

```
TranscripcionVideoCept:
 Test  tests/acceptance/TranscripcionVideoCept.php
 Step  Click "Open transcript"
 Fail  Link or Button or CSS or XPath element with 'Open transcript' was not found.
```

This is the snap image from makeScreenshot. As you can see, the 'Open transcript' link exists:
[image: snap on makeScreenshot]
So, why works on first but doesn't on second case?

Comment: Please provide HTML code of that menu.

Comment: the code is so complex and lot of tags to write on the message. I think the best option is navigate to www.youtube.com/watch?v=l03aH7TWLck and inspect the code by yourself.

Comment: Probably complexity of the code is the problem.

Comment: Try use `.style-scope.ytd-menu-service-item-renderer` css selector.

Comment: Unfortunately, that dont works :(